# CSS @media print counter(page) issue

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an issue regarding the content: counter(page) in my media print.
The counter of the page disappears if the margin is set to 0:

```html
  @page {
    counter-reset: page;
    size: A4;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    @top-right {content: counter(page);}
    }
```

On the other hand, if I do not use the margin set to 0, other elements appear on the corners of the page, such as website URL, title, and current date, which I do not want.

I was wondering if there is a way in which I can make the counter page appear after using the margin:0 or if I can hide the other 3 elements if I do not use margin 0.

Any help or advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently because of the fact that the print view settings are User based, there is only so much you can do regarding this matter.

Either use margin:0; and make all the 4 elements disappear (current date, website title, page counter and website URL), or use all of them as they are.

There are also some differences in browsers regarding the window.print(); command, Mozilla and Internet Explorer 11 do not have a print view and will instead download the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only setting the bottom and top margins to 0?

```
margin-bottom:0;
margin-top:0;
```

Comment: Yes, but they all disappear if i do that

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu Ahhh. I get what you need now. I looked around and nothing straight forward for this. I dig some more tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, I could not find anything regarding this matter myself. Nothing usefull at least, and I tried to find random websites that could have this "fixed" but nothing so far.